# ggplot2 legend add 95% confidence interval

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to add an error bar in the legend to indicate a 95% confidence interval. I want it to be a single color. I have three groups of estimates that are plotted across three different colors using ggplot()+geom_point+geom_error_bar(). The current legend only has the geom_point in the legends and I turned off the geom_error_bar() legend.

How can I add a random addition to the legend to indicate the 95% confidence interval as a single error bar that is a neutral color?

Comment: Can you please show us a reproducible example of your problem? A verbal description isn't really enough to show us what you want here.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.